# Forward slash problem in xsl and xsql

Tags: xml, xslt, xsql

I have simple xsql

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="zad1.xsl" ?>

<page xmlns:xsql="urn:oracle-xsql" connection="java:comp/env/jdbc/mondialDS">
    <xsql:query max-rows="-1" null-indicator="no" tag-case="lower" rowset-element="continents">
        select name as continent 
        from mondial_user.Continent
        order by 1
    </xsql:query>
</page>
```

which gives me a list of continents with "australia/oceania" among them

i use XSL on above xsql :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- Root template -->
 <res>
  <xsl:template match="/continents">
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
      <re>
        <xsl:value-of select="continent"/>
      </re>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</res>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Firefox throws an error on "wrong formated xml document" with:

AfricaAmericaAsiaAustralia/OceaniaEurope

-----------------------------------^

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**It appears that somehow you are processing not the XML shown above, but the result from the SQL Query**.

Also, your XSLT code is not valid XSLT (although it appears to be wellformed XML) because of the `res` element that is not within any template and is in no namespace..

There is also possibility that the reported error could be in your XSLT code  -- in the parts of the code that you have not shown.

Please, provide a complete (but minimal possible) example of the XML document and the XSLT stylesheet that when run will really produce the error.

Comment: thoose two are complete documents ( imean xsl and xsql ) . Should i provide separate namespace for res element ?

Comment: @Peter-Kaleta: If you don't provide a complete example, how can people repro the issue and then investigate it? The chances of getting help are thus minimal...

Comment: again , those documents are Complete. Ty for help I managed to get this working by adding root element to xsl